# combining two arrays from different classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

An action runs two searches on two distinct classes. Class First has attributes `price, a, b, c` while Class Second has attributes `price, d, e, f` .

Can a controller action then sum the two arrays and sort by price

```
@all_results = @search_results_first + @search_results_second
```

where the view can be invoked, having logic for column data adjusted for the origin `@search_result`

```
@all_results.each do |result|
  <tr>
  if @search_results_first.include?(result)
    <td><%= result.a %></td> <td><%= result.b %></td> <td><%= result.c %></td> <td><%= result.price %></td>
  else
    <td><%= result.d %></td> <td><%= result.e %></td> <td><%= result.f %></td> <td><%= result.price %></td>
  end
  </tr>
end
```

Comment: `@all_results.sort_by(&:price)` will do the sort..

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You can sort the merged array inside the controller:

```
@all_results = @search_results_first + @search_results_second
@all_results = @all_results.sort_by(&:price)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, do the sorting as below:

```
@all_results = (@search_results_first + @search_results_second).sort_by(&:price)
```

In your view, you can [check the type of object](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/is_a%3F) to render different attributes:

```
@all_results.each do |result|
  <tr>
    if result.is_a?(ClassFirst)
      <td><%= result.a %></td>
      <td><%= result.b %></td>
      <td><%= result.c %></td>
    else
      <td><%= result.d %></td>
      <td><%= result.e %></td>
      <td><%= result.f %></td>
    end
    <td><%= result.price %></td>
  </tr>
end
```